# How to setup ProtonVPN in Docker and let use Firefox use this connection?

Tags: docker, vpn

I want to configure some programs like Firefox and Thunderbird to use ProtonVPN's VPN connection in a Docker container. I can change the network / proxy settings in these programs, so this should be possible. But I need an advice / tutorial.

I found this repository: https://github.com/tprasadtp/protonvpn-docker/tree/master/docs

How can I use this docker image (ideally with docker-compose) on my Windows host and how can I set the correct settings in Firefox on my host machine to use the docker image's VPN connection?

First of all, I need a running ProtonVPN container with a static IP address, I guess?
Then which settings do I have to set in Firefox?

Thank you very much.